# Fourier Optics Filtering

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

I was assigned an experiment of Fouriers optics where I have to use different Filters. One of them was the dark spot and the tiny hole. As of my understanding, for tiny hole, we cut off all high-frequency light related to diffraction and refraction, thus using only the low freuency part of the initial image. The result would be a limited yet very clear image on the screen. While for the black spot we cut off the concentrated beam and project only the high frequency diffracted and refracted beams. Thus we get a rather unclear image? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi,  you may find it helpful to read about complementary apertures and about the spot of  Arago .  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arago_spot   and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babinet%27s_principle

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I suppose I am right, isn't it?